# java - how to eliminate of primitive type and get unused of local variable

Tags: java, local-variables, primitive-types, bcel

i have an example simple code :

```
class Test {
    void method(boolean boo){
        String b;
        int a=0;
        try
        {
            java.awt.image.BufferedImage image=null;
            new Thread().sleep(1000);
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"test");
            java.io.File file=new java.io.File("C:\\file.png");
            boolean boo=file.exists();
            if(boo==true)
                image=javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
}
```

Basically i have to use BCEL to access the byte code and reach my objective.
so, i have try create simple code :

```
import org.apache.bcel.Repository;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.*;

class javap
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            JavaClass jc = Repository.lookupClass("Test");
            ConstantPool constantPool = jc.getConstantPool();
            Method [] method=jc.getMethods();
            for (Method m : method) 
            {
                LocalVariableTable lvt=m.getLocalVariableTable();
                LocalVariable[] lv=lvt.getLocalVariableTable();
                for(LocalVariable l : lv)
                {   
                    System.out.println(l.getName()+" : "+l.getSignature());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
local variable : this --> LTest;
local variable : image --> Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
local variable : file --> Ljava/io/File;
local variable : boo --> Z
local variable : ex --> Ljava/lang/Exception;
local variable : this --> LTest;
local variable : a --> I
```

How to eliminate primitive types that have been retrieved like `a` as `int` and `boo` as `boolean`, and how to retrieve unused local variable like `String b` ?

-Thanks-

Comment: That `catch` in `Test` throws nothing... sigh

Comment: rakeb.void: considering the contents of the try block, I think this can be overlooked here.

newbie: you can use Wrapper classes to get rid of the primitives, and the line with b, you can just delete or comment out. that way, your code (where you have two variables with the name b) might become compilable.

It seems to me, you don't know naming conventions, and have quite a messy code. It might suit you best to read up on the basics before starting more complex code.

Comment: @Stultuske, OP was not asking for optimization tips on Test.  he/she was asking for tips on usage of BCEL library.  I believe the code in Test is messy on purpose and anyone who does bytecode parsing is hardly a newbie

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: @sharonbn "anyone who does bytecode parsing is hardly a newbie" ..
first of all: his (user)name is newbie, which is why I addressed him like that. secondly, even a newbie can copy paste code he doesn't understand, even if that code is about bytecode parsing.

Comment: if you noticed his/her name, you might as well have noticed his/her reputation....

Comment: this is not only unhelpful, it is also spiteful and plain mean. I wish I could vote down a comment

Comment: good for you. congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding retrieval of unused local variable: I ran your code and I see that the `LocalVariableTable` doesn't seem to contain the unsued String.  When I "use" it by initializing it, the variable will be added to the table.  I searched and according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632799/do-unused-local-variables-in-a-method-acquire-memory-in-jvm) the JIT (or perhaps the compiler? since it is the one creating the bytecode) optimizes the code and removes the unsued var completely from the bytecode.

Comment: what do you mean by "elimination" do you want to detect primitive types in the `LocalVariableTable` or modify the bytecode and remove the variable?

Comment: from result i want to not showing "boo" and "a" because both of them are primitive type.

Comment: Seems preatty obvious to me just by looking at the printout: anything not starting with `L` is primitive

Comment: i think u right, but is some method in bcel to looking at them, so i will not print them ?