# Java bytecode LocalVariableTable contains duplicate entry for a single local variable

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

Here is my sample java code.

```
package com.test;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class TestASMIns
{
    public void process(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String userName;
        if(request.getParameterMap().containsKey("username"))
        {
            userName = request.getParameter("username");
        }
        else
        {
            userName = "UNKNOWN";
        }
        System.out.println(userName);
    }
}
```

In above example local variable **userName** declared inside of method body. AFAIK bytecode instruction for above code should contain only one LocalVariableNode for variable **'userName'**(Since it is not declared within any inner scope/block). But bytecode instruction for LocalVariableTable contains duplicate entry for variable **'userName'**. Can someone shed some light on this.

Here is the bytecode instructions: (generated using **javap**)

```
  public void process(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest);
    descriptor: (Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: invokeinterface #16,  1           // InterfaceMethod javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap:()Ljava/util/Map;
         6: ldc           #22                 // String username
         8: invokeinterface #24,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.containsKey:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        13: ifeq          28
        16: aload_1
        17: ldc           #22                 // String username
        19: invokeinterface #30,  2           // InterfaceMethod javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.getParameter:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        24: astore_2
        25: goto          31
        28: ldc           #34                 // String UNKNOWN
        30: astore_2
        31: getstatic     #36                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        34: aload_2
        35: invokevirtual #42                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        38: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
        line 12: 16
        line 13: 25
        line 16: 28
        line 18: 31
        line 19: 38
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      39     0  this   Lcom/test/TestASMIns;
            0      39     1 request   Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;
           25       3     2 userName   Ljava/lang/String;
           31       8     2 userName   Ljava/lang/String;
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
        frame_type = 28 /* same */
        frame_type = 252 /* append */
          offset_delta = 2
          locals = [ class java/lang/String ]
}
```

Comment: A local variable is considered defined only in ranges of bytecodes where it has been assigned a value, i.e. is not uninitialized garbage. Since you didn't initialize it in the declaration, it is unassigned from 0 through 24, assigned at 25 (one instruction with length 3), unassigned from 28 through 30, and assigned from 31 through 38.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the clarification. Tried initializing  **String userName = null;** gives expected result. But i have one doubt. In above example the value initialized with if condition blocks should accessible till end of the method body right? i.e both **userName** LocalVariable should contain range through 38 right? Why if(true) block LocalVariable ends with index 30?

Comment: Reason has been explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632799/do-unused-local-variables-in-a-method-acquire-memory-in-jvm

Comment: At index `13`, there is a conditional jump `ifeq` to the location `28` that will be taken if `containsKey` returns `false`. If taken, there will be no valid value for `userName` yet. The instructions `28: ldc #34; 30: astore_2` are storing the constant string `"UNKNOWN"` to it so *after* the completion of the `astore_2` instruction, there will be a valid value. Therefore, for the range `[28 - 30]`, the variable has no valid value. But this is irrelevant to the used memory, as the slot number 2 will be reserved throughout the entire method execution whether containing a valid value or not.