# Java: how many bytes needed to transmit double data type array containing nulls?

Tags: java, amf

If I pass an array of data type double having 100 elements (for example) from an application server's (Linux CentOS) Java (1.6) method to a client using a binary transfer (e.g. [AMF protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format)), how many bytes are transmitted?

For example, if it were an array of double floating-point numbers, each number occupies 8 bytes. So, if the array is 100 elements long, and each element were null, would an array size of 800 bytes be transmitted? That is, does each element still occupy 8 bytes if it is null?

UPDATE:

Ultimately what I'm getting at with the above question, is I have a (x,y) data set on a server that represents a plot. The y data is unique, but the x-data is equally spaced. So, I can avoid transmitting the x-data from the server to the client (instead transmitting the x-interval and let the client re-create the predictable x-axis values). However, the array being passed from the server to the client appears as:

```
myArray[0].x = null
myArray[0].y = 1e-302
myArray[1].x = null
myArray[1].y = 1.42e-202
...
myArray[99].x = null
myArray[99].y = 2.3234e-3
```

and I'm wondering if those `null` values are going to each be 8 bytes long or if I'll get some memory savings because they are `null`.

UPDATE 2:

PDF page 82 here for the BlazeDS (e.g. LCDS) [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/LiveCycleDataServicesES/3.1/Developing/lcds31_using.pdf) describes conversion from Java to ActionScript AMF3 (used by BlazeDS and LCDS). On PDF page 83 the table shows Java type `null` maps to ActionScript AMF3 type `null`.

Comment: This is highly context-dependent.

Comment: that is 100% up to the protocol.  is it actually AMF or is that just an example?

Comment: AMF seems to encode nulls with one byte (0x01, the type byte) and doubles with nine bytes (the type byte followed by the 8-byte double). In that case, you will save a lot by encoding nulls instead of regular data values.

Comment: Thanks nneonneo, is that in the documentation somewhere you could point me to?

Comment: It's in the Wikipedia article that you linked to in your question.

Comment: -1 - The wording of this Question is confusing and self-contradictory.  1) 1t asks about "space occupied" but it is really about bytes transmitted. 2)  It asks about binary formats in general, but it is really about a specific format. 3) Then the updates throw in irrelevant data structures and an link to a 6Mb PDF that is barely relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AMF0, according to [the Wikipedia article you linked to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format), a "number" (AMF0's only numeric type, but it corresponds to Java's `double`) will be nine bytes (`0x00` to indicate it's a number, plus eight bytes for the number's double-precision floating-point representation), whereas a `null` will be just one byte (`0x05`). An array contains two bytes (initial `0x08` and final `0x09`) plus its contents, so if the array has length *n*, and *k* of its elements are numbers, then its total size will be 2 + 9 × *k* + (*n* − *k*) = 2 + *n* + 8 × *k*. As you can see, `null`s can potentially reduce the transmission payload significantly.

AMF3 differs in details, but is similar.

Comment: Great, thanks. I noticed PDF page 83 in the linked LCDS documentation above shows BlazeDS (e.g. LCDS) maps Java type `null` to AMF3 type `null`, which helps fill in the answer a little, as now the Wikipedia link shows the AMF0 (assumed to be same as AMF3) `null` occupies 1B.

Answer (score 2):

There is no DOUBLE data type in Java SE. Since it's nullable, then we're talking about [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) (and not `double`). Instances of the wrapper type (`Double`) use considerably more memory than values of the primitive type (`double`).

Any null reference will use *less* memory than the memory consumption of a reference to instance of a class plus [the memory used to store the instance itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420032/139010). You might naively assume that a null reference uses 4 or 8 bytes (depending on whether you're using a 32- or 64-bit JVM) but there are [fancy-schmancy optimizatons that the JVM can use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop) to *potentially* reduce the size of an object reference (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348008/memory-allocation-how-much-space-does-a-reference-occupy-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430655/java-does-null-variable-require-space-in-memory)).

Either way, if you're so concerned with memory usage, *why are you using `Double` at all, instead of `double`?* If it's just because you need a "no value" value, **use [`Double.NaN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN).**

Comment: He's not asking about memory usage, but about a transmission protocol (AMF).

Comment: The client needs to receive the model structure as shown above, that is, the `myArray[i].x` needs to be present, and in the client it is populated with double.